# How can I add a PersistentBottomSheet right away when a Widget gets created?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

How can I add a PersistentBottomSheet right away when a Widget gets created, instead of putting the code to show it in a callback to a button press or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `StatefulWidget`'s `initState` to do actions on first render.

Normally it's not possible to rebuild the layout inside `initState`. But you can instead schedule a rebuild right after the fist render using `Scheduler`.

```
@override
void initState() {
  SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    Scaffold.of(context).showBottomSheet(builder)
  });
  super.initState();
}
```

Don't forget to import `import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';`